# How to prove that a particle or a body moves in a circular trajectory with respect to centre of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

In some situations in mechanics,  observing motion of bodies with respect to centre of mass often gives useful insights to visualize the situation and obtain  many results.In some cases the motion of particles/rigid bodies with respect to centre of mass (COM) is circular. I would like to illustrate with the help of an example:

A small ball of mass $m$ is placed in a circular tube of mass $M$ and radius R (cross section radius of the tube << R) which is kept on a horizontal plane in gravity free space. Friction is absent between tube and ball. Ball is given a velocity v. Then,  path of ball with respect to COM will be circular.Now, sometimes it becomes intuitively difficult to realize the nature of path and I tried to assume velocities of the ball and tube at a general time t , conserve momentum and kinetic energy of the system but it did not prove the required result .I would like to know a general method which can deal with this example  and other similar question where  we need to prove that the  path of a body with respect to COM is circular .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It doesn't make sense to consider the path of a single ball with respect to the center of mass of the ball, because the COM is always at the center of the ball and does not move with respect to the ball. Unless you're also considering the mass of the tube in calculating the COM.

Comment: If the ball is constrained to move on a circular path, then it can only have trajectories along that circle. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circle is the set of all points in a plane at a given non zero distance from a reference point called the "centre".

By making a diagram of the tube and ball at any given moment, it is clear that the
centre of mass of the system is at a distance of MR/(m+M) from the small ball, on the radius joining the centre of the loop and the small ball.

Therefore at any given moment the ball is at a constant distance of MR/(m+M) from the centre of mass of the system. Therefore it lies on a circle.

This situation was relatively simple and the path of the small ball turned out to be circular wrt COM. However the system is non rigid and one can't say for certain if the path of each point of the system is circular about the COM. However for rigid bodies, every point moves in a circle in the reference frame of the centre of mass, no matter how complex the motion is.

(the system is non rigid because the small ball isn't fixed in position wrt the loop)